# Why browser waits for ajax call to complete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I using following simple AJAX call in my html page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: MY_URL;
    });
});
```

This ajax call takes approximately 10 minutes to complete. But, I am unable to navigate away from the page until ajax call finishes. I want to let ajax call run on the server without waiting for response.

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate away?

Comment: Browser keeps on loading for 10 minutes until ajax call finishes.

Comment: That won't happen by default so either there's more code which you didn't post causing a problem, or your server has issues

Comment: I know, this shouldn't happen by default. There is nothing more code on client side. Does code at server side matters?

Comment: Ajax calls don't disable browser navigation. *Regular* calls don't disable browser navigation. There's something else going on, like an `ajaxSetup` or something else.

Comment: I have tried same code on my production server as well. Still same behavior. Also, I have tried removing this ajax call from code and then after loading page, I executed this ajax call from browser console, still same behavior.

Comment: What backend is this? php? is it preventing session logic from occuring because the current session is still locked by the endpoint the ajax request is requesting?

Comment: Yes, it's PHP with Apache server.

Comment: Here's a test to be sure... While the ajax request is loading... try opening the page in another tab. I suspect it will also wait for the ajax request to complete, thus ruling out the ajax request entirely.

Comment: Yes, I tried this already. Page doesn't open on another tab as well.

Comment: TLDR release the session before you begin whatever makes the ajax request take a long time.